# How to change the icons for my enterprise wiki library items

Tags: document-library, custom-list, css, page-layout, publishing-site

I am working on a publishing site collection and I am using the enterprise wiki template. But inside the “Pages” library I will get an IE icon beside the items as follow:-

[image]

So is there a way to change this icon , to a custom image ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could either change the icon for htm pages in the hive (its ichtm.gif by default ["ic" for icon and "htm" for filetype]) or overwrite it by CSS or JS.

Here's a example for plain CSS:

```
img[src="/_layouts/15/images/ichtm.gif"] {
   background-image: url("http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f0/Pdf_16x16_Crystal_SVG.png");
   height: 0px;
   width: 0px;
   padding: 8px;
}
```

Here's some JS (plus jQuery) magic:

```
$('img[src="/_layouts/15/images/ichtm.gif"]').attr("src", "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f0/Pdf_16x16_Crystal_SVG.png");
```

This will replace all images referring to the old IE icon with a custom one.

And here is the path to the icon if you want to replace it in the hive - `\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\TEMPLATE\IMAGES\ichtm.gif`